# Apache tomcat doesn't recognize git stashed and later git stash applied changes

Tags: maven, tomcat, tomcat7, git-stash

I had a repository with code that I was testing via running a server at localhost. The standard procedure was to start Apache-Tomcat-7, re-build the project using Maven and deploy it.

After a while of coding I decided to `git stash` current changes, then built and deployed the old version, it ran correctly in all browsers. After that I called `git stash apply`and once again built and deployed the created .war file. However, despite the correct version of code both in generated war and in the deployed .war, now none of the browsers see the new applied version.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, removing cached files, shutting down Tomcat & deleting the logs & starting it again. And yet the changes, despite being correctly deployed, don't appear in browsers when I navigate to localhost.

How to fix it, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the web application with your new code built correctly but is not deploying due to an error in the web.xml, init() or classloaders.

Look for a **pair** of lines in the catalina.out file that looks like this:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/web-apps#uits#qr.war
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/web-apps#uits#qr.war has finished in 5,123 ms
```

If you see an error after the "Deploying" line and/or no "Deployment" line, that might explain the issue.